# DEBOUNCE JS NOT WORKING with event onclick was added at HTML Tag

Tags: html, events

I am learning about debounce js, and know its simple syntax as follows.

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
let timeoutId;
return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        fn();
    }, delay);
}
```

I create a button to test it as follow

```
<button id="test-debounce" onclick="testDebounce()">Click me</button>
```

function testDebounce().

```
function testDebounce() {
   debounce(() => {
      console.log('test debounce')
   }, 500)
}
```

But it not work.
I try again with

```
document.getElementById("test-debounce").addEventListener('click', debounce(() => {
    console.log('test debounce');
 }, 500))
```

It's oke. I don't undetstand. Can anyone explain for me ?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the return value of `testDebounce()` as the event handler. Here, because you are using the attribute-event syntax, you are actually passing an anonymous `(event) => eval("testDebounce()")` as the handler. ... finding a dupe isn't that easy, lots of unrelated stuff, but I'm sure there are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`debounce` is designed to create a debounced function.

Every time you click you create a debounced function which you never call.

Create the function once:

```
const testDebounce = debounce(() => {
  console.log('test debounce')
}, 500);
```

… and then use that as the event listener.

Comment: They already know how to make it work, they want to understand why it didn't work the first time.

Comment: Which I spent the first half of this answer explaining

Comment: No you didn't, that doesn't explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Yes I did, yes it does.

Comment: Thank for replying me. As @Kaiido said, I want to understand why it didn't work with first way

Comment: @blackCrow – See the first two paragraphs of this answer!